# Equivalent to \hapto for kappa-notation

Tags: chemmacros

In `chemmacros` I can use `\hapto{3}` to indicate the "hapticity" of a ligand, and the output is an upright Greek eta (well, maybe not upright) with the number as superscript. But for "denticity" a kappa should be used instead. I can use `\Chemkappa` to get the letter, but is there a command similar to `\hapto` that produces it with the superscript?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
\newcommand{\dento}[1]{\Chemkappa\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I already created one replicating the `\hapto` definition from `chemmacros`. My question was if there was already some existing macro (with an implicit suggestion to include one in future versions).

Comment: @Jellby there isn't... if you have a feature request it's best to write me an email or to use https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues

Comment: @Jellby since I am planning a new release of `chemmacros` in a few days I'm going to add something for the denticity

Comment: @cgnieder Great, so I don't need to add the feature request. Thank you.